Equation of light path in a uniform gravitational field
I am trying to get the equation of the light path in a uniform gravitational field. I start with the metric:
$$ ds^{2} = \left( c^{2} + 2 g z \right) dt^{2} - dx^{2} - dz^{2} \tag{1} $$
Light follows the null geodesic:
$$ 0= \left( c^{2} + 2 g z \right) dt^{2} - dx^{2} - dz^{2} \tag{2} $$
For motion in the direction of the gravitational field $dx = 0$ so
$$ 0= \left( c^{2} + 2 g z \right) dt^{2} - dz^{2} \tag{3} $$
This integrates easily giving:
$$\begin{align}
z \left( t \right) = \frac{g t^{2}}{2} + c t, \tag{4.a} \\
z \left( t \right) = -\frac{g t^{2}}{2} + c t \tag{4.b}
\end{align}$$
For the light moving perpendicular to the gravitational field, I have a problem, I have a differential equation with two unknowns:
$$ 0= \left( c^{2} + 2 g z \right) - \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^{2} -\left( \frac{dz}{dt} \right)^{2} \tag{5} $$
I need more information (another equation?) to find the path equation (I know it is a parabola). Do you have any suggestions? I could not find anything in the literature.

Where did you get that metric? Nothing wrong with it, but it's not the usual Schwarzschild (that at least some use), so it might be useful to specify where you got it to see if that resource might also have a solution.

I got it from AI. It is derived straight from the general solution of the EFEs by approximating e^(gz) with 1+2gz

This is fundamentally a good question, I think; I would recommend using a standard weak-field metric or the Schwarzschild metric, though. Generative AIs are very useful tools in writing but I have found that they have a very hard time with physics. (Welcome to Physics SE, by the way.)

I also found a complete derivation here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-can-the-rindler-metric-be-derived-for-a-uniform-gravitational-field.251960/. It clearly gives the correct result for light moving in the direction of the gravitational field. I do not know how to move forward in the case of light moving perpendicular on the gravitational field. Thank you for the welcome, BTW

By the way: Instead of your solution (4.b) I get $z(t)=\frac{gt^2}{2}-ct$.

Yes, I know, I have a specific reason to writing the way I did in 4.b.


For the light moving perpendicular to the gravitational field, I have a problem, I have a differential equation with two unknowns ...

At first glance this looks like a 2+1D case with a sort of $g$-field in the $z$-direction, uniform across the $x$ coordinate.
If by "perpendicular" you mean "moving in the $x$-direction spatially" (which given your metric appears to be the case, please correct me if I'm wrong), then you should be able to set $u^z=\frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}\tau}=0$ so the $\frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}t}$ term vanishes.
The equation you produced is the general form of the trajectory of the light beam, not just the perpendicular case. Indeed there is not enough information, as given, to determine everything. In this case you would have to specify an initial velocity in the $z$ or $x$ directions and a $z$-position to get the unspecified velocity, or two velocities to get a $z$-position. There are nonzero connection coefficients here though, so if you set $u^z=0$ to get a perpendicular trajectory, it won't remain valid for long because the worldline of the photon will be curved.

dz/dt is 0 ONLY at t=0. The trajectory is a parabola, so , in general dz/dt is not 0. I need one more equation in order to find the solution. I am very tempted to use dx/dt=c, though this is true only in approximation. I am am surprised I cannot find any literature on this relatively simple exercise. Thank you for helping me and you are absolutely correct in terms of the setup.

I am trying to solve the issue of how long it will take a ray of light to travel a distance w across the lines of force of the uniform gravitational field g.
